# Open and close connection in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, transactions, dblink

I have below procedure in which i am inserting the data into temp_soap_monitoring table using select statement. I have soap_monitoring table in `FONIC_RETAIL` database  from where i want to take the data and insert into temp_soap_monitoring table. I am performing the scheduler job of every 5 minutes for this procedure so that i always get the latest data from soap_monitoring@fonic_retail table. The problem of this procedure is that it takes too much cost and query execution time to run this procedure. Every time it try to fetch the data from db link and save it my local database. I remember in jave, php and other programming languages we have method to open the db connection when we tried to fetch data from db link and then once the insertion is done we can close the db connection. So the performance improves and it also does not put load on db link. In this method we dont have to assign db link to fetch the data. So i belive is there any way to apply this logic in my oracle procedure. The question arises because right now i am hardcoding the db link but now i have 3 more db links and i dont want to duplicate the same procedure by assigning diffferent db links.

```
PROCEDURE  "EXT_SOAP_MONITORING" AS

LAST_SM_ID Number := 0;
LAST_CAPT_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

SELECT LAST_TASK_ID INTO LAST_SM_ID FROM CAPTURING where DB_TABLE='TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING';

insert into TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING(ID,REQUEST_XML,RESPONSE_XML,WEB_SERVICE_NAME,WEB_METHOD_NAME,CREATE_DATE,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE)
select ID,REQUEST_XML,RESPONSE_XML,WEB_SERVICE_NAME,WEB_METHOD_NAME,CREATE_DATE,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE from
SOAP_MONITORING@FONIC_RETAIL WHERE WEB_SERVICE_NAME ='RatorWebShopService'  and WEB_METHOD_NAME = 'placeShopOrder' and ID > LAST_SM_ID order by ID desc;

update
CAPTURING set LAST_TASK_ID=
CASE WHEN ((SELECT MAX(ID) from TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING) IS NULL) AND (LAST_TASK_ID  IS NULL)  THEN (SELECT MAX(ID) from SOAP_MONITORING@FONIC_RETAIL)
WHEN (SELECT MAX(ID) from TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING) IS NULL THEN LAST_TASK_ID + 1
ELSE (SELECT MAX(ID) from TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING) END,
CAPTURING_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LAST_CAPTURED_DATE = LAST_CAPT_DATE where DB_TABLE='TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING';

END EXT_SOAP_MONITORING;
```

Comment: Why you don't write triggers? OR materialized view also an option.

Comment: Is there any way to open and close db connection in triggers ? And the logic will remain same i think if i use trigger or procedure ?

Comment: Also do you know which part of the procedure is the top consumer? What is the top event there?

Comment: i didn't get your question.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at AWR?

Comment: No i havent heard of AWR. I will look into this concept.

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK <user_supplied>;
```

[Reference](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1132640)

Comment: I have seen the referance you have provided but i really not aware of how can i apply this logic in my procedure for db links using alter session. It will be really helpfull if you can give small example related to my procedure. So in this case i dont need to hardcore and assign db link in my select query ?

Comment: I did't check it, you please add it in your procedure at last line.

Comment: Ok but this is for closing the database link but how can i open the database link and in this case do i need to hardcore and assign db link in my select query ?

Comment: @Rahul: the connection will automatically be opened by Oracle if you access the DBLink

Comment: Bus as i mentioned i have many procedures and i cant use ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK at the end of each and every procedure because it will give me an error i.e DB link in use .

Comment: But you insist to provide solution for closing db connection thats why I have provided that. Let me know in which scenario you need to close because in all ways db connection will be in use if you have multiple procedures running.

Comment: I think then in this case i cant use ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK. In any other programming language like for example java we have possibility to open a db connection run some queries and once it is done then close the connection. I m writing all the procedures inside package and want to close the connection once the procedures inside package  are not using it.

Comment: you should insert this statement in last procedure of package.

Comment: I tried to put that in my last procedure where i am calling other procedure inside the package. It executes and then i tried to run this command just to check whether the db connection close or not using this query :select * from v$dblink;  But it still does not close the connection.

Comment: have you provided connected user in this statement

Comment: No i haven't because i am running the query with the same user where i have created db links

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92726/discussion-between-rahul-and-muhammad-muazzam).